# Import module from adjacent directory in pytest

Tags: python

In `test_app`, I have tried appending `'../../src/app.py'` to `sys.path`, `from ...src.app import function` or `from app import function` but I keep getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`. Not sure how to overcome this seemingly simple issue.

```
├── src
│   └── app.py
├── tests
│   └── unit_tests
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── conftest.py
│       └── test_app.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the full path to the parent folder, then import `app`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../../src") 
# We can now directly access 'app' as we have a pointer to its parent directory

from app import function

# Use 'function' here
```

Comment: I already did this but I keep getting the same error...

Comment: Are you sure @DSteman? I just copied your directory structure locally and it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm sure. I recreated this structure in a new project folder and keep getting the same error.

Comment: That's very strange @DSteman - which error are you receiving? Is it still 'no module named "app"'?

Comment: @DSteman I get the error too but only when I'm running it from a different folder. If you run the file from its root directory it works. I'm just trying to figure out why that's the case...

Comment: Interesting. Also if I run it from the root of the project I get the error. Even I set `PYTHONPATH` to `pwd`.

Comment: That's intriguing - this is beyond my expertise unfortunately, but do let me know if I can help out more @DSteman :)